# stop flash from flickering

Tags: jquery, flash, xhtml

I have embedded flash in my html pages but upon refresh, it flickers, is there anyway to stop this? I don't mind a jquery solution.

Comment: What do you mean with flickering? Do you have a link for us? The loading of flash takes some time, so maybe in the first second(s) you'll see only the flash background color.

Comment: i am developing locally but this link(http://24timezones.com/online_clock.php) is a good example of what i mean. Wait for the clock on the top right corner to load, then referesh...how can i stop that, cus i have applied meta referesh to each of my pages and its looks weird when it changes to the next one.

Comment: Are you serious? Refreshing the page reloads everything including the SWF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't not have Flash (and as a matter of fact any plugin) reinitialise itself on page reload.

I'm afraid if you might have to consider rearchitecting your website to refresh content partially using AJAX instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of exported swf Vs the player version. You may have exported SWF for version of flash player that is not available in browser plugin.